# Returning FALSE when using multiple THEN statements

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro that has conditional statements in. It works perfectly if I take out the second statement of coloring the cell with the error message. Instead when I add the color to the cell I am returned with a FALSE statement in my column.

It works perfectly here:

```
Sub trantype()

Dim cell As Range
Dim lastRow As Long
Sheets("1099-Misc_Form_Template").Select
lastRow = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row

For Each cell In Range("C2:" & "C" & lastRow)

    If cell.Value <> "C" And cell.Value <> "" Then cell.Offset(0, -2).Value = cell.Offset(0, -2).Value & ", Tran type error" 

Next
End Sub
```

But when I add the second condition I am returned with a FALSE statement:

```
Dim cell As Range
Dim lastRow As Long
Sheets("1099-Misc_Form_Template").Select
lastRow = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row

For Each cell In Range("C2:" & "C" & lastRow)

    If cell.Value <> "C" And cell.Value <> "" Then cell.Offset(0, -2).Value = cell.Offset(0, -2).Value & ", Tran type error" & cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 37

Next
End Sub
```

I would like both conditions to be met, so the error message is printed in the offset cell and the cell with the error in to have color.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put each command into its own row. The `&` ampersand is a text concatenation operator. It cannot be used to chain commands.

```
For Each cell In Range("C2:" & "C" & lastRow)

    If cell.Value <> "C" And cell.Value <> "" Then
        cell.Offset(0, -2).Value = cell.Offset(0, -2).Value & ", Tran type error"
        cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 37
    End If

Next
```

This way you need to use the `End If` statement, so don't forget that.

Comment: Side note: the `:` (*instruction separator*) token can be used to chain multiple instructions in the same logical line of code. Not that I'd recommend doing that (especially in `If....Then thing1 : thing2`, where it's relatively ambiguous whether `thing2` runs conditionally or not - definitely prefer `If...End If` block syntax)